# Can this stack air duct be removed to tear down small wall?

Tags: drywall, shower, ducts, support, demolition

I have an appointment with the HVAC supply business that installed the furnace 2 years ago but it is months away. My question is can I remove this wall to make my shower bigger? Through research I think it is not a return vent because it is in the bathroom. I don't need a vent at all in the bathroom, the bedroom has another duct and vent that is ok. Can I just cut this stack duct out and tear the wall down and patch the floor and ceiling, saying I can cap it in the attic?

Also I am worried is this a load bearing wall? I and got sledgehammer crazy hating my small shower.[image]

Wall I need to get rid of to extend shower. [image: Wall I want to get rid of. It's 3' deep connects to vent to air vent about 2 feet right of this picture in bathroom]

Comment: It is not a vent for the bathroom as it is coming from  somewhere and going to somewhere.  Where ?

Comment: Yeah, I'd think that vent is going from down below to up above and using the shower wall as a convenient highway to get there. I see no sign of a vent on this side and would be astonished if there was an outlet venting into the wet shower stall. (That would make for a goose-bump shower when the AC kicks in!)

Answer (score 0):

You might think you don’t need a duct in the bath but this may well be keeping you from having a mold issue. I seriously doubt that is a load bearing wall. But if you don’t want it it would be simple to remove and blank off.